exception when using EJB jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.global
I'm working in a Java project (swing interface) and i'm trying to use EJBs , but I have alsways same problem :
Here is the exception , I tried to create JAR file from EJBs (with intellij idea and deploy it in wildfly but doesn't work :
deploy JARs on wildfly
contenet deployed on wildfly
excepetion when I click button 'connexion' 
Bonjour
déc. 01, 2024 11:55:19 PM org.wildfly.naming.client.Version 
INFO: WildFly Naming version 2.0.1.Final
déc. 01, 2024 11:55:20 PM org.wildfly.security.Version 
INFO: ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 2.3.0.Final
déc. 01, 2024 11:55:20 PM org.xnio.Xnio 
INFO: XNIO version 3.8.16.Final
déc. 01, 2024 11:55:20 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio 
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.8.16.Final
déc. 01, 2024 11:55:20 PM org.jboss.threads.Version 
INFO: JBoss Threads version 2.4.0.Final
déc. 01, 2024 11:55:20 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl 
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 5.0.29.Final
here
global -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.global
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: global -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.global
at Makhloul.ilyas.view.client.Authentification$2.actionPerformed(Authentification.java:130)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2314)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:407)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6621)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3398)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6386)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4996)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4828)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4828)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:775)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:98)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:747)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:744)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: global -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.global
at org.jboss.as.naming@34.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:89)
at org.jboss.as.naming@34.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:190)
at org.jboss.as.naming@34.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:176)
at org.jboss.as.naming@34.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:172)
at org.wildfly.naming-client@2.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteServerTransport.handleLookup(RemoteServerTransport.java:200)
at org.wildfly.naming-client@2.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.naming.client.remote.RemoteServerTransport$1.handleMessage(RemoteServerTransport.java:120)
at org.jboss.remoting@5.0.29.Final//org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionChannel.lambda$handleMessageData$3(RemoteConnectionChannel.java:432)
at org.jboss.remoting@5.0.29.Final//org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl$TrackingExecutor.lambda$execute$0(EndpointImpl.java:993)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.16.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Process finished with exit code 0
My EJBs :
IclientAuthentificationRemote
 package Makhloul.ilyas.EJBs;
    import jakarta.ejb.Remote;
    
    @Remote
    public interface IclientAuthentificationRemote {
    
        public int Sauthentifier(String username, String password);
    }

IClientSessionRemote :
 package Makhloul.ilyas.EJBs;
    
    
    import jakarta.ejb.Remote;
    
    @Remote
    public interface IClientSessionRemote {
    
        public void seConnecter(int id );
        public void deconecter() ;
    }

ClientAuthentificationBean :
package Makhloul.ilyas.EJBs;


import jakarta.ejb.*;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

@Stateless
@Remote(IclientAuthentificationRemote.class)

public class ClientAuthentificationBean implements IclientAuthentificationRemote {
    @Override
    public int Sauthentifier(String email, String password) {
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        try {
            // Obtenez la connexion via DBConnection
            connection = DBConnection.getConnection();

            if (connection == null) {
                System.out.println("Impossible de se connecter à la base de données.");
                return 0;
            }

            // Requête SQL pour vérifier l'email et le mot de passe
            String sql = "SELECT id FROM clients WHERE email = ? AND password = ?";
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, email);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, password);

            // Exécutez la requête
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            if (resultSet.next()) {
                // Si une correspondance est trouvée, retournez l'ID du client
                return resultSet.getInt("id");
            } else {
                // Si aucune correspondance n'est trouvée, retournez 0
                return -1;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        } finally {
            // Fermez les ressources
            try {
                if (resultSet != null) resultSet.close();
                if (preparedStatement != null) preparedStatement.close();
                if (connection != null) connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

ClientSessionBean
 package Makhloul.ilyas.EJBs;
    
    
    import jakarta.ejb.Remote;
    import jakarta.ejb.Stateful;
    
    @Stateful
    @Remote(IClientSessionRemote.class)
    public class ClientSessionBean implements IClientSessionRemote {
    
        int clientId ;
    
    
        @Override
        public void seConnecter(int id ) {
            this.clientId = id;
        }
    
    
        @Override
        public void deconecter() {
            this.clientId = -1;
        }
    }

and here button to authentified
connectButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Bonjour");
            String email = emailField.getText();
            String password = passwordField.getText();

            if (email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() )
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainPanel, "Veuillez remplir tous les champs!", "Erreur", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            else {


                try {


                  Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();
                    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
                    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://localhost:8080"); // URL de votre WildFly
                    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "root"); // Nom d'utilisateur si nécessaire
                    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "Ilyas2024"); // Mot de passe si nécessaire



                    // Initialisation du contexte JNDI
                    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(env);
                /*  Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();
                    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
                    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:8080"); // Adresse de votre serveur WildFly

                    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(env);*/
                    IclientAuthentificationRemote clientBean = (IclientAuthentificationRemote) ctx.lookup("java:global/wildfly-naming...0.1.Final/ClientAuthentificationBean!Makhloul.ilyas.EJBs.EJB.IclientAuthentificationRemote");

                 //   IclientAuthentificationRemote authService = (IclientAuthentificationRemote) ctx.lookup("java:global/gestionHotel_RMI_EJB/ClientAuthentificationBean!Makhloul.ilyas.IclientAuthentificationRemote");

                 //   IClientSessionRemote userSession = (IClientSessionRemote) ctx.lookup("java:global/gestionHotel_RMI_EJB/ClientSessionBean!Makhloul.ilyas.IClientSessionRemote");
                    int  clientId = clientBean.Sauthentifier(email , password);
                    if(clientId==0)  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainPanel, "Erreur de connection!", "Erreur", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    else if(clientId==-1)   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainPanel, "Email ou password incorrect!", "Erreur", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Bienvenur Monsieur "+clientId+" !");
                       // userSession.seConnecter(clientId);
                    }


                } catch (NamingException ex) {
                    System.out.println("here");
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                }



            }
        }
    });

